# notifyAll() not awakening processes

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify, dining-philosopher

I'm programming a little Java program where I need to create threads (philosophers in my code), and these philosophers need to change of state between thinking, hungry and eating. 
I'm not that far into the project and I have the next problem:

```
public class NewMain {

    static Philosopher [] p;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p = new Philosopher[5];

        p[0] = new Philosopher(0);
        p[1] = new Philosopher(1);
        p[2] = new Philosopher(2);
        p[3] = new Philosopher(3);
        p[4] = new Philosopher(4);

        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            try{
                p[i].run();

                if(i == 4) {
                   p.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e) {}   
        }  
    } 
}
```

I'm creating 5 philosophers(threads). Each one of those has a `wait()` instruction in their code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int rand;

    if (status == 0) {
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " is waiting.");
        try {
            wait();
            System.out.println("Awoken");
            while(status == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " is thinking.");
                    sleep(100);
                    rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,100);                    
                    if(rand > 95){
                        status = 1;
                        System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " changed state to hungry.");
                    }
                }
        }    
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e) {}
    }
}
```

The problem is that when invoking `notifyAll()`, the processes don't awake and they just die after executing the `run()` method of each thread.

If anyone is wondering, I'm not using `synchronized` because I need to run the methods at the same time.

Also, I've tried to put `notifyAll()` inside the `run()` method of the threads.

Can anyone tell me what's going on and why are the threads not continuing
with their code?

Comment: you have to call `Thread.start()` rather than `Thread.run()` if you want to to attach your `run()` into an actual OS thread.

Comment: Why are you calling run to start a thread? Run will execute just like a method, it will not initiate your thread. What is the need of notifyAll here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problems

1. `notify[All]()` and `wait()` should be used on the same instance. You are notifying on the array `Philosopher[] p`, but waiting on `this` which is a `Philosopher`. It's like ***I*** am waiting for **you**, but **you** are notifying **Sarah** that you're going to be late.
2. You **have created** the threads but **haven't started** them properly. Calling `run` will execute the method in the current thread. Use the method `start` instead. It begins execution concurrently.
3. To use `x.notify[All]()` or `x.wait()`, you have to be within a synchronised block `synchronized(x) { ... }`. Ignoring `IllegalMonitorStateException` won't help you at all.

### Answers

> ... why are the threads not continuing with their code?

They might call `wait` **after** the 4th thread notifies them.

> ... the processes don't awake and they just die ...

They don't die, **they still wait** until you terminate the program.

> I'm not using `synchronized`because I need to run the methods at the same time

You need to run the methods at the same time **correctly**, right? Here, synchronisation is required at least for building `wait-notify` communication.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is an array of Runnable. when you write

```
p[i].run();
```

Then, you are invoking `run` method (actually you haven't started a thread here instead called `run` method) using object stored at `p[i]` location. Now, as per [`notifyAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll())

*Wakes up **all threads** that are **waiting** on **this object's monitor***. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.

1. You should have used `start()` instead `run()` to start a new thread.
2. `notify()` and `notifyAll` are used when thread(s) are waiting to acquire monitor on ***current object***.